# IBM MQ authentication

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting following error while trying to connect with IBM MQ. I have done enough configuration in MQ Explorer but still getting this error.

```
**MQ Config:**
```

```xml
        <InputDef name="Order" type="mq">
                <property name="message.flow" value="OrderFlow" />
                 <property name="queue.adapter" value="com.tplus.transform.runtime.external.queueutils.ibmmq.IBMMQAdapter" />
                <property name="queue.ibmmq.manager" value="QM1" />
                <property name="queue.ibmmq.host" value="localhost" />
                <property name="queue.ibmmq.port" value="1414" />
                <property name="queue.ibmmq.channel" value="CH1" />
                <property name="queue.name" value="Q1" />
                <property name="queue.ibmmq.headertype" value="jms" />
            </InputDef>
    
    
       </InputDefs>
    
       <OutputDefs>
    
        <!-- Instantiate a RMIOutputHandler that is registered in the JNDI with the specified devicename
             The output is written to the specified directory -->
        <OutputDef name="Order" type="rmi">
            <property name="output.device" value="device.order" />
            <property name="output.writer" value="com.tplus.transform.runtime.external.output.mq.QueueOutputDeviceWriterFactory"/>
            <property name="queue.adapter" value="com.tplus.transform.runtime.external.queueutils.ibmmq.IBMMQAdapter" />
            <property name="queue.ibmmq.manager" value="QM1" />
            <property name="queue.ibmmq.host" value="localhost" />
            <property name="queue.ibmmq.port" value="1414" />
            <property name="queue.ibmmq.channel" value="CH1" />
            <property name="queue.name" value="Q2" />
            <property name="queue.ibmmq.headertype" value="jms" />
        </OutputDef>
```

**Error Logs:**
[log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1j58.png)[log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1j58.png)

Comment: What error are you getting?  Your question doesn't include an error.

Comment: You tried to link to a `jpg` that includes the error.  If you have a text based error, just copy and past it into the question, you can click edit and do this.  You can add ``` before and after the content to make it format as a fixed width with linefeeds so it comes out well.  You should only post screen shots where it makes sense such as asking about a GUI issue.  Screen shots are not searchable, so anyone in the future searching for `MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED` would never find this question.  Specific to that error you will need to look at the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` for the cause.

Comment: On an instance running localhost on 1414, It's unusual not to see something like `DEV.APP.SVRCONN` for channel and `DEV.QUEUE.1` for queue. So I am guessing that you have configured and created those channels and queues deliberately.

Comment: @Gopinathm G Looking at your screenshot I can see you have an MQ return code of 2035 which means you were Not Authorised to use one of the MQ resources you tried to use. Here is some [doc on IBM Developer](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/articles/mq-dev-cheat-sheet/) which walks through debugging for this error code. As JoshMc says, the MQ AMQERR01.LOG will contain more information and help determine the next steps.

Answer (score 4):

Did you disable authorisation for the queue manager QM1?

Try this:

Create connection for MQ Explorer

```
runmqsc QM1

define channel(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN) chltype(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('mqm')
alter qmgr chlauth(DISABLED)
refresh security
```

After these commands use Channel SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN instead of CH1. Or try to change SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN to CH1 in the command.

Change access permissions for rfhutil

```
runmqsc QM1

ALTER AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) 
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```